# Combining STRING_AGG with JSON_ARRAY in T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2022

Has anyone experienced issues when running a command like this in SSMS?

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(JSON_ARRAY(COL1, COL2, COL3 NULL ON NULL), ', ') 
FROM 
    {schema}.{table}
```

In my case this closes the connection to SQL Server with an error:

> Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 42
> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

- SSMS 19.3
- Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Express Edition (64-bit)
- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0

To work around this issue I split this activity into 2 steps:

1. Create a temp table with rows created using `JSON_ARRAY`
2. Combine all rows into array of arrays with `STRING_AGG`

Comment: That syntax, `JSON_ARRAY(COL1, COL2, COL3 NULL ON NULL)`  What is that? What is **null ON null**?

Comment: @IanBoyd, it's a new [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-array-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server 2022.

Comment: Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in SQL Server, are you on the latest build?

Comment: definetly bug. Exception Address = <frame id="00" address="0x7FFE0481495E" pdb="SqlTsEs.pdb" age="2" guid="697D2AEF-4939-4B69-8935-9DAFC9E3A3ED" module="SqlTsEs" rva="0x495E" />
Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Access Violation occurred reading address FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)  

Can anyone with newer build / CU confirm it's been fixed?

Comment: Well there are a huge amount of bugs and security issue fixed on the CUs, you really should upgrade pronto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was [fixed in CU1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate1#2081891):

> 2081891 : Fixes an exception that occurs when `JSON_ARRAY`/`JSON_OBJECT` return values are used in a parameter in functions that take strings. After you apply this fix, return values of `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_OBJECT` are made coercible and can be used as string parameters.

So I ***strongly*** suggest you upgrade to [the latest CU](https://www.sqlserverversions.com/2021/07/sql-server-2022-versions.html), for this and many other reasons (security, performance, other bug fixes).